# Why is not apache2ctl on OSX?

Tags: macos, apache, apache2

I'm trying run some server script which is using there lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
export APACHE_CONFDIR=$SOME_DIR
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl start
```

But it doesn't works, because I have 'apachectl'. After change it works but not in $SOME_DIR directory.

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: @Marc B The command 'apache2ctl' simply doesn't exist on OSX.

Comment: apache2ctl might just be a symlink pointing at apachectl. `ls -l /usr/sbin/apa*` and see what comes up.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  3822 Aug 23  2015 /usr/sbin/apachectl

Comment: so use that instead...

Comment: As I noticed in my question, after this I CAN run apache ('It works!' on 'http://localhost'), but the environmental variable 'APACHE_CONFDIR' is not passed. Therefore the local *.conf files are not used..

Answer (score 2):

Because they never had an ambiguity due to installing both Apache 1.3 and Apache 2.x on the same operating system. "apache2" is a debian-ism.